# SMTP module cannot connect to smtp.gmail.com

Tags: 7

The SMTP module stopped working about a week ago. It is no longer able to connect to smtp.gmail.com.  I have tried commonly recommended remedies:

- Allow "Less secure apps" in Google settings.
- Visit http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha and click the button.
- Switch to port 587 and TLS.
- Turn the SMTP module off and then back on.

I am still not able to send emails.  This seems to have happened without any changes to the site.  The debug output:

```
SMTP.module is active.
The configuration options have been saved.
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-SIZE 35882577 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8 "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [66.228.44.53] 250-SIZE 35882577 250-8BITMIME 250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES 250-PIPELINING 250-CHUNKING 250 SMTPUTF8
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "334 VXNlcm5hbWU6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6 "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534-5.7.14 Learn more at "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> ERROR: Password not accepted from server: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbs 534-5.7.14 ayHmWfTW3uH_Y0l9QBdB8thX_D2gyq0cU5Ltn0zJWruuXlc4Bvxyeag-Md22UG22XWJJX 534-5.7.14 kFJOLwtOF7Agw6KdzAL_P3IQZlAY-bSuSgKpM_aD8Rzd7AAIdpfRWkwd9bXW-wWw> 534-5.7.14 Please log in via your web browser and then try again. 534-5.7.14 Learn more at 534 5.7.14 https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754 f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was ""
SMTP -> get_lines(): $str is "221 2.0.0 closing connection f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> get_lines(): $data was "221 2.0.0 closing connection f19-20020ac859d3000000b002de4d014733sm11933677qtf.13 - gsmtp "
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: @byemsg
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known (0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed to use an app password. This is done at https://myaccount.google.com/security

Before creating an app password, you have to turn on 2-factor authentication for the account.